# Зависание Android Studio после обновления

Tags: android-studio

Недавно вышла стабильная версия Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1, я обновился на неё, и после этого обновления начались постоянные зависания, чаще всего замечал зависания после запуска приложения, нажимаю запуск, и интерфейс просто завис, ничего не работает пока не перезапустишь студию (принудительно закрыв), выделял память как студии, так и для gradle в (users/name/.gradle).
Искал что-нибудь похожее, но ничего не нашёл, у некоторых просто фризы/лаги, у меня же наглухо виснет, свободной памяти около 3К, всего на ПК 16ГБ.

ПК:
Проц: Intel Core i5-8300H
Видео: GeForce GTX 1050 (2GB)
ОЗУ: 16GB 2666 (двухканал)

Если нужны какие-то логи или дампы, подскажите где их достать, я вытяну.

Скрин студии, как зависло:
[image: Студия после зависания]

Answer (score 0):

В общем, переустановил Windows и вместо Android Studio установил Intellij IDEA. Теперь такой проблемы нет, думаю что достаточно просто переустановки Android Studio.